# Bootstrap Modal resizing from centre rather than edges

Tags: css, jquery-ui, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have a dynamic bootstrap modal thats contents are populated by making a request to my asp.net core routes and overwriting the html content from the response. I have added the JQuery UI Resizable class to the modal. When resizing, the modal resizes from the centre rather than the edge case.

Code for adding resizable options to modal:

```
var $modal: JQuery = $('#blah_ModalPopup > .modal-content');

$modal.resizable({
        alsoResize: '.configuration-container, .modal-dialog',
        // Sizes
        minHeight: 300,
        minWidth: 450,
        maxWidth: window.innerWidth -20,
        // Functions
        resize: function (e, ui) { // Fired when the handle in the bottom right corner is clicked and dragged.
            $('.configuration-container').css("max-height", "fit-content");
        }
    });
```

HTML structure of my modal:
[image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayrz6.png)

If there are any suggestions as to why its resizing from the centre rather than just the edges, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Good to know that you have implemented it but what can we do about it?

Comment: From all the docs i had seen, it all works from the edge case, not from the centre! Looking for an idea into why its resizing it this way!